# How to I install the default Grub theme for ubuntu?

Tags: grub2

I installed Ubuntu Mate on my Ubuntu 15.04 install just to try it out. It's pretty nifty, but it's replaced my minimal grub theme (with a purple background) with a gray-green menu I don't like in the least. I tried using Grub Customizer to change the look of Grub but I'm not having much success: the only theme that's available in Grub Customizer is the Ubuntu Mate one, and my efforts at a custom theme aren't working very well (for some reason my 1920x1080 wallpapers are not being properly rendered). Any thoughts on how I can get the minimalistic grub menu that comes with ubuntu unity back?

Answer (score 2):

The default theme is provided by [`plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo). Install it:

```
sudo apt-get install plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
```

To set it as the default, run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

And select `/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth` in the menu.